# How to get data from arrays inside of array

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, react-hooks

I'm working on an project that uses React with hooks and typescript. I'm currently trying to get data from arrays inside an array that I get from my json response. Data what i log after data handling looks like this:

```
[
    [
        "2021-09-07",
        43
    ],
    [
        "2021-09-08",
        47
    ],
    [
        "2021-09-09",
        52
    ]
]
```

So the question is, how can i get the numerical values seen in the json, to an array?

EDIT: Got it working now. Had to add this:

```
const numbers = data.map((item: any) => item[1]);
  console.log(numbers);
```

Thanks alot @Ryan Le

Comment: Show in more detail in what format you need to receive data

Comment: I just want the data like this: [43, 47, 52]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You would map all the numbers from the original array like so:**

```js
type Data = [string, number][];

const data: Data = [
  ["2021-09-07", 43],
  ["2021-09-08", 47],
  ["2021-09-09", 52]
];

const result = data.map(item => item[1]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey, i tried your solution but im getting this error: Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Comment: Ah, you are on `typescript`, I updated my answer

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am. I got it working now, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

If by numerical values you mean the second element of each array such as (43 , 47 , 52) you can simply map to a new array like this

```js
const oldArray = [
  [
      "2021-09-07T08:53:34.4067874+00:00",
      43
  ],
  [
      "2021-09-07T09:53:34.4067881+00:00",
      47
  ],
  [
      "2021-09-07T10:53:34.4067884+00:00",
      52
  ]
]
const newArray = oldArray.map((el)=>
  el[1])
console.log(newArray)
```